# Do notable applications use cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, particles

I'm French so excuse my poor English.

I'd like to know is if Tiny Wings, Angry Birds, and other great applications like that use cocos2D, for some or all of their game. I want to use the particle designer and we must use  it with cocos2d, but I don't like the fact that the image of cocos2d appears on my application on the App Store.

Comment: You have asked 18 questions here and accepted not a single answer. You might want to think about that for a second...

Comment: What Toastor is saying is, "vous devez vous rendre à chaque question que vous avez déjà demandé et cliquez sur la case à cocher par la réponse la plus appropriée à l'accepter. Aider les gens à obtenir la reconnaissance. Si vous n'avez pas "accepter" les réponses en cochant les gens sont moins susceptibles d'aider. Vous devez augmenter votre "accepter taux« aussi proche que possible de 100%"

Comment: @Jarrod Thanks for taking the time to translate and describe it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiny Wings, Angry Birds, Mega Jump, Trainyard... to name a few, use cocos2d, box2d, or both.

[Source: A description of a cocos2d book that I'm waiting to be released.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321735625)

Also... you can change the default loading image of the application... easily.

-- EDIT --

To remove the frame rate from your application, remove the following line of code from your app delegate file:

```
[[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

Or, you can leave the line there but set it to `NO`.

Comment: so are you sure of that. So according to you angry birds and other change the default loading image of the application.

Comment: Change the default.png image.  What they have is just a placeholder for your actual image.

Comment: ok but what about the numbers that appaers at the left bottom of th screen, can we remove it. Because when we see this we can say that the app was made with cocos 2d

Comment: I went to the cocos 2d website but I don't fins the name of angry bird or tiny wings .

Comment: Angry Birds and Tiny Wings use Box2D, but I think neither use Cocos2D. So you and the linked page are quite right, but it's not relevant to the poster. Though they easily could.

Comment: @arvin Arabi: I will tell you how to remove the little framerate numbers in the bottom corner if you accept my answer.  =)

Comment: it's done well can you tell me how to remove the framerate please ?